# Python Selenium help finding xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

[image]

Can you help me? I need to find the element.

I have tried this so far :

> browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="text"]/text()')
> browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[type="text"]/text()')
> browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/input[@type="text"]/text()')
> browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/input[type="text"]/text()')
> browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="text"]')

None of them turned out working. ):

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page you are working with? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to find this element with the text input. I cant really share the website because its only accessible with a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:
`browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@class,"ScInputBase")]').get_attribute("value")`
I guess it's a value, not a text.
Also use `find_element_by_xpath`, not `find_elements_by_xpath`
I'm not sure about the uniqueness of the locator I used since I can't see your page.

Comment: That is correct as Eliyahu mentioned, and please also make sure to copy the full xpath path of the desired element you need.

Comment: @tamerjar the full `xpath` of the specific element is not relevant here

Comment: @Eliyahu I get this error using the code : Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[contains(@class,"ScInputBase"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[contains(@class,"ScInputBase"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the closing `)`

Comment: Now it should be correct. But again, I'm not sure about the uniqueness

Comment: @Eliyahu Maybe a stupid qustion but can you only do a if statement by using elements and not element? So without a s at the end?

Comment: `findElements` returns a list of web elements while `findElement` returns single web element. SO you can not directly `click` or `getAttribute` on what the `findElements` returns without mentioning index of the element inside the list